Permission error while trying to run TTS from Coqui's beginner tutorial
I'm trying to work with Coqui TTS, following the tutorial for beginners https://docs.coqui.ai/en/latest/tutorial_for_nervous_beginners.html, but I keep running into a permission error. I’m using the following code for training:
import os
import torch
from trainer import Trainer, TrainerArgs
from TTS.tts.configs.glow_tts_config import GlowTTSConfig
from TTS.tts.configs.shared_configs import BaseDatasetConfig
from TTS.tts.datasets import load_tts_samples
from TTS.tts.models.glow_tts import GlowTTS
from TTS.tts.utils.text.tokenizer import TTSTokenizer
from TTS.utils.audio import AudioProcessor

output_path = "tts_train_dir"
dataset_config = BaseDatasetConfig(
    formatter="ljspeech", meta_file_train="metadata.csv", path=os.path.join(output_path, "LJSpeech-1.1/")
)

config = GlowTTSConfig(
    batch_size=32,
    eval_batch_size=16,
    num_loader_workers=4,
    num_eval_loader_workers=4,
    run_eval=True,
    test_delay_epochs=-1,
    epochs=1000,
    text_cleaner="phoneme_cleaners",
    use_phonemes=True,
    phoneme_language="en-us",
    phoneme_cache_path=os.path.join(output_path, "phoneme_cache"),
    print_step=25,
    print_eval=False,
    mixed_precision=True,
    output_path=output_path,
    datasets=[dataset_config],
)

ap = AudioProcessor.init_from_config(config)
tokenizer, config = TTSTokenizer.init_from_config(config)

train_samples, eval_samples = load_tts_samples(
    dataset_config,
    eval_split=True,
    eval_split_max_size=config.eval_split_max_size,
    eval_split_size=config.eval_split_size,
)

model = GlowTTS(config, ap, tokenizer, speaker_manager=None)
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model = model.to("cuda:0")

trainer_args = TrainerArgs()
trainer = Trainer(
    trainer_args, config, output_path, model=model, train_samples=train_samples, eval_samples=eval_samples
)

trainer.fit()

When I try to run it, I get the following error:
 > TRAINING (2024-11-09 17:42:08) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\trainer\trainer.py", line 1833, in fit
    self._fit()
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\trainer\trainer.py", line 1785, in _fit
    self.train_epoch()
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\trainer\trainer.py", line 1503, in train_epoch     
    for cur_step, batch in enumerate(self.train_loader):
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 484, in __iter__
    return self._get_iterator()
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 415, in _get_iterator
    return _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter(self)
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 1138, in __init__
    w.start()
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 45, in __init__      
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 154, in get_preparation_data     
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 134, in _check_not_importing_main
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path    
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "d:\Dataset AI Voice\TTS\train.py", line 69, in <module>
    trainer.fit()
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\trainer\trainer.py", line 1860, in fit
    remove_experiment_folder(self.output_path)
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\trainer\generic_utils.py", line 77, in remove_experiment_folder
    fs.rm(experiment_path, recursive=True)
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\fsspec\implementations\local.py", line 183, in rm  
    shutil.rmtree(p)
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 757, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 627, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\1luki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 625, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'D:/Dataset AI Voice/TTS/tts_train_dir/run-November-09-2024_05+42PM-dbf1a08a\\trainer_0_log.txt'

Despite following the tutorial instructions, I'm stuck with a persistent "permission error" that I can't seem to troubleshoot. Does anyone have tips or suggestions for dealing with permission issues in this setup?
To try to fix it, I added the following code to move the model to GPU if available:
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model = model.to("cuda:0")

I also saw that running the command CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python train.py,
but I’m not quite sure how to use that command, so I just ran python train.py instead.
